# Asynchronous url validation causing problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rss

I am building a type of RSS Feed reader using Google's Feed API.  After much trial and error, I have been able to instantiate a connection to a given RSS URL via PHP, and return the JSON object.  The problem I run into is that I am attempting to validate multiple URLs from an array, but due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX, and loading time lag through the Google API, the results code fires off before the validation can complete.  I have tried things like: forcing synchronicity, setTimeouts, .promise on objects that call the validation, ect but I'm getting no where.  Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

My Code:
PHP

```
$feed = $_POST['feed'];
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=&q=" . $feed;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, www.mywebsiteurl.com);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $body;
```

This snippet successfully creates a connection to the given Feed URL, and returns a JSON object containing the feed data.  I am calling this external php script with the following AJAX call:

AJAX:

```
var conn = $.ajax({
     url : "php/feedlog.php",
     type : "post",
     data : {feed: feed_a[i]}
});

conn.done(function (data){
    var err = eval('(' + data + ')' ).responseStatus;
    if (err==200){
        console.log("Success");
    } else if (err==400){
        console.log("Failure with: " + err);
    }
});
```

This code works flawlessly for a single connection attempt, but I need to linearly step through an array of feeds, testing a feed, waiting for the connection result, then proceeding to the next feed in the array, or breaking on a successful connection.

I have attempted to use an $.each statement for feed_a[], but the loop fires faster than the results can be returned.  I think I need to operate a buffer, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

As always, if needed I can provide additional code, previous attempts, or greater clarification upon request.  If needed I can host the code live at my website for demo purposes.

**More direct question:**  How can I force a loop ($.each, for loop, or a recursive function) to wait for results from an AJAX call?

*Also, in an attempt to make my questions better in the future, could someone explain why my question may have been marked down?*

Edit:  Thanks for the speedy response everyone!  The following code appears to resolve my issue:

```
$.each(v_feed, function(_,url){
    $.ajax("php/feedlog.php",{
        type: "POST",
        data: { feed: url }
    }).done(function(data){
        var err = eval('(' + data + ')' ).responseStatus;
        if (err == 200){
            console.log("success with: " + data);
        } else if (err == 400){
            console.log("fail with: " + data);
            console.log("removing from valid array");
            v_feed.splice(v_feed.length - _, 1);
        }
        //console.log(err);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("Fail");
    }).complete(function(){
        console.log(v_feed);
    });
});
```

Comment: "How can I force a loop ($.each, for loop, or a recursive function) to wait for results from an AJAX call?" You don't do that. You use relative callback/method to request and set logic according this. You could pass an array of deferred/promise objects to `$.when`: `$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises);`

Comment: @Wolff Would be able to provide a basic example of this, or a website that does?  I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean by relative callback / method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through with $.each, creating the wrapper for each feed in the html before you send the ajax request, storing a reference to the wrapper. On done, populate the wrapper with the feed. This will allow you to retrieve them all at once while still adding them to the page in the correct order without having to wait for them all to complete.

```
$.each(feedArr, function(_,url){
    var wrapper = $("<div>").appendTo(someel);
    $.ajax("feed.php",{
        type: "POST",
        data: { url: url }
    }).done(function(data){
        // process data...
        wrapper.append(generateFeedHTML(data));
    }).fail(function(){
        wrapper.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: This actually answers a question I haven't encountered yet, and will be very useful for my upcoming task of displaying the content.  Luckily, in my application the results do not need to be displayed on page until a valid feed has been selected.  Thank you!  I will be referencing this comment for future tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
var arrayOfPromises = [];

//inside each/for loop, push request in array
arrayOfPromises.push($.ajax({
     url : "php/feedlog.php",
     type : "post",
     data : {feed: feed_a[i]}
}));
```

And then outside of loop:

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises).done(function(data){
     //all requests are done
});
```

I don't remember exactly which data will be passed to done(), check it.

Comment: each set of arguments from each ajax request will be sent to the done argument list as an array for each. For example, in your code, `data` will be `[parsedResponseText,statusCode,jqXHR]` representing the first request. Best way to handle this would be to loop over the `arguments` array-like thingy.

Comment: @KevinB as usual, thank you! Your answer is more appropriate, i guess

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for my problem as per my initial tests.  It connects to each url, returns JSON Data, validates status code, then .when ensures I can omit the bad connections, and move forward with content validation on successful feeds.  Thank you!

Comment: *".when ensures I can omit the bad connections"* Not necessarily. If any one of them fails, the done callback will not be triggered. I'd suggest making sure none of them fail by having php always return 200 success, then testing if anything was returned for each request to see if it failed.

Comment: I see.  The Google Feed API always returns a status code, so the php script can only fail to return a value if the URL is improper.  Using your method listed above seems to work more consistently in a wider range of scenarios, and I am able to remove failed connections from the array, leaving me with an array of valid connections.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Fire off the next call only on success:

```
var worked = {status:true},
 conn = function(successLogic){
 if(feed_a[i]) // I assume this is the loop end condition...
   $.ajax({
     url : "php/feedlog.php",
     type : "post",
     data : {feed: feed_a[i]},
     success: function(data){
       if(successLogic(data));
         worked.status = worked.status && conn(successLogic); // Recursion instead of iteration!
     },
     error: function(err){
       worked.status = false;
       // your error code
     }
   });
   else
     return worked;
};

var completedRecusionPromise = conn(function(data){
  var obj;
  try{
   obj = JSON.parse(data);
  }catch(e){ console.log(e); }
  return !!obj; // Assuming you just want valid JSON??
});
```

Comment: Edited to use var outside closure and only return on case where you're at end of feed, used object so it's promise-like state